# My HTML snippetes content not show in the display

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain to me about the HTML snippets? See the image below (w3schools HTML snippets tutorial). Then I create a "content.html" file according to w3schools instructions. Then I create another .html file and then use the same code but don't show any content to the display. Can someone explain me how to use it?

[image]

When I try to my computer -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an error that occurred when loading your page that should that you can find in your console log similar to

html.html:1

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///content.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.

This occurs as a result of the file being loaded using the file protocol rather than the HTTP protocol, due to the absence of a web server. As browsers do not allow you to load local files using the File protocol using an HTTP request. Which is what the code below is trying to do.

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
        if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
        /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
        elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
        includeHTML();
    }
}
```

To get this to work on your local system you would have to set up a web server. And access the HTML file using localhost. Depending on your intentions for implementing this you could look for a web server that will be suitable. However, I would advise Apache Server, using XAMPP which is relatively easy to install.

Comment: Thank u so much. It works to my local server using Xampp